# How do I identify a Pokémon nest?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm visiting my parents,  and I've noticed their town has a Magnamite and Voltorb infestation.

I've [read about Pokémon nests](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4t3o06/examining_nests/),  but the way to identify them is by seeing multiple of the same Pokémon on your radar at the same time.

I think we've had an update since that reddit post...since then I don't remember seeing multiple of any Pokémon
on my radar.

How can I identify (and prove the location of) a Pokémon nest ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nests are a rather complicated and debated part of Pokemon GO's research communities as of now.

Nests are typically closely-collected groups (meaning if you are in the middle of the nest, you will be able to see every spawn from said nest).

Typically, you can identify a nest by seeing a specific Pokemon (or multiple!) spawning in the same place on the map in a repeating and predictable fashion.

As the Nearby mechanic has been removed, the game no longer clues you in to the fact that there are nests nearby. As such, you actually need to go on the map to find them.

Note, however, that nest-caught Pokemon have a higher statistical chance of having weaker/lower IVs, thereby making them not as useful to Trainers. As such, it is advised to only use them for candy-farming for higher-IV Pokemon.